# What is a word for the feeling of being complimented?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that describes the feeling of receiving praise? The only thing I could think of is “flattered,” but it doesn’t have the right connotation for what I’m looking for. Maybe “feeling of being complimented” isn’t the right description, more like the feeling of a prideful person getting their ego stroked?

I think the reason why “flattered” doesn’t feel right is because it implies that the person was surprised by the compliment and is happy to be receiving it. But the word I’m looking for is more the feeling of thinking “well of course, I’m amazing and I deserve this.”

Ex, “It was a strange compliment, but he was too distracted feeling ___ to care.”

Comment: Is it pride you feel? Are we going for one syllable? How will we know when we are close?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *Inflated* maybe?

Comment: Some people are *embarrassed* when they get a compliment.

Comment: [flattered](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flattered) fits this exactly according to Merriam-Webster. I don't think it always has connotations of surprise, although people will often feign surprise when flattered.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciated ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appreciated)): recognized as having value. Sentence examples for "feeling appreciated" in https://www.google.com/search?q=%22feeling%20appreciated%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

"Feeling appreciated" can be used for both "feeling from being complemented" and "feeling from being valued".